# Using an array as function arguments for scipy integration

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

For the program I'm currently working on, I'm taking coefficients for a fit line from a file. For example, one line of the file might have the coefficients `a` and `b` in `y = a + bx`, or a similar function.

I've been importing the coefficients and converting them to a `numpy` array. I would then like to integrate the function numerically using `scipy`'s integrate library. However, as some of the lines have a large number of coefficients, and the number of coefficients is not constant between the lines, I would like to pass in the function arguments to the integrating function as an array.

As a simple example I'd like to make something like the following code work:

```
import scipy.integrate
import numpy
def integrand(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a + b*x + c*x**2 + d*x**3
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 4
coefficients = numpy.array([a, b, c, d])
answer = scipy.integrate.quadrature(integrand, 0, 1, args=coefficients)
```

The code functions correctly if I replace the last line with

```
answer = scipy.integrate.quadrature(integrand, 0, 1, args=(a, b, c, d))
```

Is there any practical way to pass in the coefficients from an array short of manually inserting each element?

Comment: have you tried `args=tuple(coefficients)`?

Comment: I had not. That works perfectly, thank you.